# How to place embedded video player so that it displays under pop out menu?

Tags: jquery, flash, video-streaming, embedded-video

I have big element at the top of the webpage that sides down with jQuery when a button is clicked. However, if the first post on the blog is a flash video, it shows up on top of the menu. Z-index doesn't help in this instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('embed').attr('wmode', 'transparent')
```

Comment: I thought that that would work too, but didn't work. I found this to work:

$('embed').attr('wmode','opaque').wrap('<div>');

But its a little inefficient as it loads and then loads a second time when its redrawn.

Comment: After that, I have been successful with FF and Chrome with this code. But can't seem to get it to work with IE.

$(window).load(function(){
    $('embed').attr('wmode','opaque');
    $('object').append("<param name='wmode' value='opaque'>").wrap('<div>');
   });

Answer (score 1):

when you embed the flash set the parameter "wmode=transparent"

Comment: Yes, I read that that works. But how can I make it so that whenever a flash video is added to the blog, it automatically adds wmode=”transparent” . As I don't necessarily expect the end user to do this.